# Achieve smoothness/Performance while dragging along with audio/screen video recording

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, audio, video

Need to have performance/Smoothness while dragging UIImageView. While using [MoveMe sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html) app of Apple, I am getting smoothness but when i implement same in my code then performance degrades.

I am also recording the Video of screen and Audio. I have already kept video and audio recording in Background due to which i gain some more performance but it is still somewhat itchy.

If you notice [PuppetpalHD](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/puppet-pals-hd/id342076546?mt=8) app on itunes it has very good smoothness. How to achieve that???

Here is my code:

On Button Click:

```
if (Isrecording ==YES)
{
    [captureview performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startRecording) withObject:nil];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startAudioRecording) withObject:nil];
    Isrecording =NO;
    [btnRecord setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else if (!Isrecording)
{
    [captureview performSelector:@selector(stopRecording) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    [self performSelector:@selector(stopAudioRecording) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
    Isrecording=YES;
    [btnRecord setTitle:@"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self performSelector:@selector(putTogether) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
}
```

Now if you see the above code, my startRecording function will record the screen. and startAudioRecording will record audio.

Below code is used for dragging the UIImageView:

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *t = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint pPrev = [t previousLocationInView:self];
    CGPoint p = [t locationInView:self];

    CGPoint center = self.center;
    center.x += p.x - pPrev.x;
    center.y += p.y - pPrev.y;
    self.center = center;
}

If I stop recording audio or video, then dragging is very smooth. How can I achieve smooth performance along with audio and video recording.
```

**EDIT:**

I have also tried using UIPanGestureRecognizer as given in http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/ But has same case as above. I am getting enough smoothness without audio and video recording but when it is included then performance degrades...

**EDIT 2:**

Is there any performance gain with `pointInside:withEvent:` compared to `touchesMoved:withEvent:`??
How to gain performance from below code while using 1st method above??

```
UITouch *t = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint pPrev = [t previousLocationInView:self];
CGPoint p = [t locationInView:self];

CGPoint center = self.center;
center.x += p.x - pPrev.x;
center.y += p.y - pPrev.y;
self.center = center;
```

**EDIT 3:**

Including my screen Video recording code part:

```
-(BOOL) setUpWriter {
NSError* error = nil;
videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[self tempFileURL] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&error];
NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

//Configure video
NSDictionary* videoCompressionProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1024.0*1024.0], AVVideoAverageBitRateKey,
                                       nil ];

NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.frame.size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.frame.size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               videoCompressionProps, AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey,
                               nil];

videoWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];

NSParameterAssert(videoWriterInput);
videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
NSDictionary* bufferAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];

avAdaptor = [[AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:videoWriterInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:bufferAttributes] retain];

//add input
[videoWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];
[videoWriter startWriting];
[videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1000)];

return YES;
}
```

Comment: How are you recording the screen? The application you link could be doing all this in OpenGL ES, and then recording from there. Capturing UIKit on every frame is going to be fairly expensive.

Comment: But, I am recording it in Background. Will that affect my performance??

Comment: Again, *how* are you recording? Are you capturing from UIKit using `-renderInContext:`? If so, that will be very slow. You only have finite CPU and GPU resources, so even moving this intensive rendering to the background will slow down processing on other threads.

Comment: I have added the code for video recording. I am simply using AVFoundation classes for recording. Is there any other alternate screen recording available for performance gain? Or it would be better to improve this one...

Comment: Hi Brad Larson, Yes, analysed the code and i am using renderInContext: api to record the screen. Is there any other alternative API to record screen compare to renderInContext:???